# How to get href's URL by using BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Could you tell me how you get `href`'s URL in the case below? I would appreciate it if you could kindly show your code to get URLs from `href`.

```
import requests as r
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = r.get('https://jen.jiji.com/')

soup = BeautifulSoup(url.text, "html.parser")

for el in soup.find_all('li', attrs={ 'class' : 'arrow03'}):
    want = el.find_all('a')
    link = el.get('href', 'no URLs')
    print(want)
    print(link)
```

Cuurently, I could get tags through print(want), but couldn't through `print(link)`.

```
[<a href="/jc/eng?g=eco&amp;k=2023011901044">(Update) Japan Daily COVID-19 Cases Halve to 96,000</a>]
no URLs
[<a href="/jc/eng?g=eco&amp;k=2023011900863">2 Universities to Be Merged as "Institute of Science Tokyo"</a>]
no URLs
[<a href="/jc/eng?g=eco&amp;k=2023011900878">(Update) Kishida Cabinet Approval Hits Record-Low 26.5 Pct: Jiji Poll</a>]
no URLs
[<a href="/jc/eng?g=eco&amp;k=2023011900770">Japan Team Develops Black Sheet Absorbing 99.98 Pct of Visible Light</a>]
no URLs
[<a href="/jc/eng?g=eco&amp;k=2023011900850">Tokyo Confirms 7,719 New COVID-19 Cases</a>]
no URLs
[<a href="/jc/eng?g=ind&amp;k=2023011801016">Solaseed Air to Fly Pokemon Jet from March</a>]
no URLs
[<a href="/jc/eng?g=ind&amp;k=2023011800979">Coinbase Announces Halt of Japan Operations</a>]
no URLs
[<a href="/jc/eng?g=ind&amp;k=2023011700996">Japan 2022 Used Auto Sales Hit Record Low</a>]
no URLs
[<a href="/jc/eng?g=ind&amp;k=2023011700892">Osaka Gas Signs LNG Deal with New Sakhalin-2 Operator</a>]
no URLs
[<a href="/jc/eng?g=ind&amp;k=2023011700427">5 Japan Drug Wholesalers to Be Fined for Bid-Rigging</a>]
no URLs
[<a href="/jc/eng?g=mkt&amp;k=2023011900934">Foreigners Turn Net Buyers of Japan Stocks Last Week</a>]
no URLs
[<a href="/jc/eng?g=mkt&amp;k=2023011900924">Dollar Weaker around 128.20 Yen in Late Tokyo</a>]
no URLs
[<a href="/jc/eng?g=mkt&amp;k=2023011900766">OSE Nikkei 225 Futures (Closing)</a>]
no URLs
[<a href="/jc/eng?g=mkt&amp;k=2023011900758">Tokyo Stocks Slide on Yen's Bounce, Wall Street Drop</a>]
no URLs
[<a href="/jc/eng?g=mkt&amp;k=2023011900697">Nikkei Average/TOPIX Index (Closing)</a>]
no URLs
```

Please give me soutions or comments

Comment: Just `el.get('href')` would do. I am not sure what the other argument is about.

Comment: @Vanitas then it returns `'no URLs'` instead of `None` if `el` doesn't have an `href` attribute [which it generally won't, since `el` would be an `li` tag according to this code].

Comment: Why not use `has_attr` method instead?

Answer (score 1):

You are close to your goal but have to iterate the `ResultSet` of `want` to get it - Would recommend to select your elements in an alternative way with [`css selectors`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors):

```
for el in soup.select('li.arrow03 a'):
    link = 'https://jen.jiji.com'+el.get('href')
    print(link)
```

*Because links are relative you have to prepend `https://jen.jiji.com`*

##### Output

```
https://jen.jiji.com/jc/eng?g=eco&k=2023011901044
https://jen.jiji.com/jc/eng?g=eco&k=2023011900863
https://jen.jiji.com/jc/eng?g=eco&k=2023011900878
https://jen.jiji.com/jc/eng?g=eco&k=2023011900770
https://jen.jiji.com/jc/eng?g=eco&k=2023011900850
https://jen.jiji.com/jc/eng?g=ind&k=2023011900956
https://jen.jiji.com/jc/eng?g=ind&k=2023011801016
https://jen.jiji.com/jc/eng?g=ind&k=2023011800979
https://jen.jiji.com/jc/eng?g=ind&k=2023011700996
https://jen.jiji.com/jc/eng?g=ind&k=2023011700892
https://jen.jiji.com/jc/eng?g=mkt&k=2023011900934
https://jen.jiji.com/jc/eng?g=mkt&k=2023011900924
https://jen.jiji.com/jc/eng?g=mkt&k=2023011900766
https://jen.jiji.com/jc/eng?g=mkt&k=2023011900758
https://jen.jiji.com/jc/eng?g=mkt&k=2023011900697
```